# mod_rewrite just broke Server-sent Event content-type?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-headers, server-sent-events

I have the following rules in my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(?:\.\w+)$

RewriteRule ^func/(.*)(/.*)?$ includes/function/post/$1.php$2
```

So I can just visit:

```
http://localhost/func/create/?ID=1
(it'll goto http://localhost/includes/function/post/create.php?ID=1)
```

It worked just fine, but if I using EventSource in javascript like this:

```
new EventSource('http://localhost/func/create/?ID=' + ID);
```

then it'll add `Accept: text/event-stream` into the **request header**,

but I noticed the Content-Type of the **response header** was `text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`,

then just throw me a **HTTP 406 Not Acceptable** status code,

(work fine if I remove `Accept: text/event-stream` in request header)

and I make sure that I added this line in my php source code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream;');
```

If I visit `http://localhost/includes/function/post/create.php?ID=1`,

everything worked just fine, Is EventSource not supported mod_rewrite?

**EDIT ---**

I tried:

```
<FilesMatch "create.*$">
    ForceType text/event-stream
</FilesMatch>
```

but it returns HTTP 404 Not Found .. : /

**EDIT 2 ---**

So I just add an new rule to override the content-type:

```
RewriteRule ^.*/(.*)/create(/.*) includes/function/$1/create.php$2 [T=text/event-stream]
```

So any file which are named with "create" will be a `text/event-stream`,

I can't apply it for all php files because I have other files

that shouldn't be a type of `text/event-stream`, but now I got an new problem..

If my php goes wrong.. It will still respond a `text/event-stream` for me ..

I'll keep finger it out :D

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_t `[T=text/event-stream]`?

Comment: Sorry, [T=text/event-stream] doesn't work, it doesn't change any header.

Comment: Just wildly guessing here; what about `AddType text/event-stream php`?

Comment: Your rule currently rewrites the url to `.../create.php/?ID=1`. If it tries to treat create.php as a directory that would result in a 404. If it treats it as path info it should be okay I think.

Comment: I just add a new rule, so I can get a `text/event-stream` content-type now, but the bad news is: it's force to be a `text/event-stream`, so if PHP just going wrong, it'll still return a `text/event-stream` for me, never mind, thank you very much!

Comment: If you solved your own problem (or at least found some kind of work-around) answer your own question in the answer-box below. You can even accept your own answer as the one that solved your problem. With this structure StackOverflow stays clean and all information stays in their designed spot.

Comment: Okay, really thank you for telling me this, I'll walk around to find more useful info, then I'll answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

So I got a temporary solution, which is force the content-type to `text/event-stream`,

just need to add this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^.*/(.*)/create(/.*) includes/function/$1/create.php$2 [T=text/event-stream]
```

So any file which are named with "create" will be a `text/event-stream`,

but it causes another problem: once your PHP error, it'll still return `text/event-stream` for you.